# *Not Iterate* Rows in Dataframe and insert column based on values in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a DataFrame and a list of dictionaries. The DataFrame has 84k rows. Each row is an account for a specific client.

Each dict in the list belongs to a specific client. They can have up to 50 keys and as few as 2 keys. The dictionaries also need to be applied in the order they are listed. The first key/value in each dict shows the name of the client the dict belongs to. The second key/value is the name of the rule.

**List of Dict Example:**

```
0 {'client': 'client 1', 'Billing Code': 'TNL', 'Valuations': '0', 'Account Number': '>99999'}
1 {'client': 'client 1', 'Billing Code': 'MF', 'User': 'BP', 'Flag': 'S'}
...
13 {'client': 'client 2', 'Billing Code': 'TNL', 'Acct Desc': '*test*}

length: 427, dtype: object
```

**DataFrame has these column names**

```
df.columns = ['Source.Name','User Bank','Bank','Account Number','Account Description','Valuation Date',
              'Preschedule','MF Flag','Load Flag','Global Flag','Money Market Flag','Days Prior to Valuation',
              'Number of Holdings','Total Assets','Unit Value/NAV','MCS Field','From Date','Valuations',
              '# Sweeps','NASDAQ','TLA','Account Type','Fund Group','Master Account Text','Master Feeder Flag',
              'Acct Flag 2','Acct Field 4','Securities At Value','Net Assets','Acct Field 1','Acct Field 2',
              'Group Account Indicator','Group Account Number','Region','Account Status','SMS Billing Code',
             'Translation Date','Portfolio Manager 1','Acct Flag 1','Dual Flag','Securities At Value Base',
             'Net Assets Base','Total Assets Base','Dual OEIC']
```

**Input DataFrame**
Dataframe containing data directly from client files

| Client Short Name | Source.Name | User Bank | Bank | Account Number | Account Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 1 | Test Account |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AC | 01 | 2 | MY ACCOUNT |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AC | 01 | 3 | SUPER FUND |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AY | 01 | 4 | S&P INDEX |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AY | 01 | 5 | Test Account |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 6 | INDEX |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 7 | Test Account |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 8 | RYAN'S Account |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BA | 01 | 1 | Test Account |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BB | 01 | 33 | INDEX |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BB | 01 | 92 | Test Account |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BZ | 01 | 123123 | INDEX |
| Client #3 | C#3.txt | BB | 01 | 1657 | Test Account |
| Client #3 | C#3.txt | BP | 01 | 15454 | Test Account |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GH | 01 | 100 | Test Account |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GH | 01 | 19875 | INDEX |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GY | 01 | 13579 | Test Account |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GE | 01 | 2 | INDEX |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GE | 01 | 72 | Test Account |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GP | 01 | 96 | GREEN Account |

**Desired Output**
Output should be the dataframe with a new column ['Billing Code'] based on the criteria from one of the 427 dictionaries.

| Client Short Name | Source.Name | User Bank | Bank | Account Number | Account Description | Billing Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 1 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AC | 01 | 2 | MY ACCOUNT | MF |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AC | 01 | 3 | SUPER FUND | HF |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AY | 01 | 4 | S&P INDEX | Index |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AY | 01 | 5 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 6 | INDEX | Index |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 7 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #1 | C#1.txt | AA | 01 | 8 | RYAN'S Account | HF |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BA | 01 | 1 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BB | 01 | 33 | INDEX | Index |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BB | 01 | 92 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #2 | C#2.txt | BZ | 01 | 123123 | INDEX | Index |
| Client #3 | C#3.txt | BB | 01 | 1657 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #3 | C#3.txt | BP | 01 | 15454 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GH | 01 | 100 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GH | 01 | 19875 | INDEX | Index |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GY | 01 | 13579 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GE | 01 | 2 | INDEX | Index |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GE | 01 | 72 | Test Account | TNL |
| Client #4 | C#4.txt | GP | 01 | 96 | GREEN Account | MF |

Column names match keys.

I basically need to iterate through each row of the data and determine if it meets the criteria in the first dict. If it does then df['Billing Code'] = that specific dict['Billing Code'] if that makes sense. If not then move on to the next billing code.

Iteration could take a very long time to run through all of this hence the "*Not Iterate*" in the title. Not sure if this is something list comprehension can do.

Thank you for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: What does it mean *if it meets the criteria in the first dict.* ? What is the criteria?

Comment: @Andrej  if I were to iterate through the dataframe and also iterate through the list of dictionaries i think it would kind of work like this. Using the first dictionary in the "List of Dict Example" above... if the row in dataframe ['Client'] = ['Client 1' and ['Valuations'] = 0 and ['Account Number'] is '>99999' then add a column to the dataframe['Billing Code'] using the ['Billing Code'] key from that dictionary. Does that make sense?

Comment: And if none criteria is met in the list of dicts, what should be the output value?

Comment: Probably N/A, but there is a rule with no criteria specified that will call them "unclassified" so I'm hoping there won't be any N/A

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the list of dicts it's in reality set of filters, where `d['client']` should be `Client #` and all keys from the dict should be equal to that client row. If they are equal, then set `Billing Code` to the code from the dict?

Comment: Correct. Not every column in the dataframe is filtered in every dictionary. Each dictionary has a different set of filters essentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Based on your comments, I'd first create a mapping `ClientID -> List of Dictionaries`:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "client": "Client #1",
        "Billing Code": "TNL",
        "Bank": 1,
        "Account Number": 1,
    },
    {
        "client": "Client #1",
        "Billing Code": "MF",
        "User Bank": "AY",
        "Bank": 1,
    },
    {
        "Billing Code": "TNL",
        "client": "Client #2",
        "User Bank": "BB",
    },
]

# create a mapping client no. -> list of dictionaries
m = {}
for d in lst:
    m.setdefault(d["client"], []).append(d)
    d.pop("client")
```

Then I'd use `df.groupby` by Client ID and apply custom function:

```py
def fn(x):
    dictionaries = m.get(x.name, [])

    out = []
    for _, row in x.iterrows():
        for d in dictionaries:
            if all(row[k] == v for k, v in d.items() if k != "Billing Code"):
                out.append(d["Billing Code"])
                break
        else:
            out.append("Unclassified")

    x["Billng Code"] = out
    return x


df = df.groupby("Client Short Name").apply(fn)
print(df)
```

The result is:

```
   Client Short Name Source.Name User Bank  Bank  Account Number Account Description   Billng Code
0          Client #1     C#1.txt        AA     1               1        Test Account           TNL
1          Client #1     C#1.txt        AC     1               2          MY ACCOUNT  Unclassified
2          Client #1     C#1.txt        AC     1               3          SUPER FUND  Unclassified
3          Client #1     C#1.txt        AY     1               4           S&P INDEX            MF
4          Client #1     C#1.txt        AY     1               5        Test Account            MF
5          Client #1     C#1.txt        AA     1               6               INDEX  Unclassified
6          Client #1     C#1.txt        AA     1               7        Test Account  Unclassified
7          Client #1     C#1.txt        AA     1               8      RYAN'S Account  Unclassified
8          Client #2     C#2.txt        BA     1               1        Test Account  Unclassified
9          Client #2     C#2.txt        BB     1              33               INDEX           TNL
10         Client #2     C#2.txt        BB     1              92        Test Account           TNL
11         Client #2     C#2.txt        BZ     1          123123               INDEX  Unclassified
12         Client #3     C#3.txt        BB     1            1657        Test Account  Unclassified
13         Client #3     C#3.txt        BP     1           15454        Test Account  Unclassified
14         Client #4     C#4.txt        GH     1             100        Test Account  Unclassified
15         Client #4     C#4.txt        GH     1           19875               INDEX  Unclassified
16         Client #4     C#4.txt        GY     1           13579        Test Account  Unclassified
17         Client #4     C#4.txt        GE     1               2               INDEX  Unclassified
18         Client #4     C#4.txt        GE     1              72        Test Account  Unclassified
19         Client #4     C#4.txt        GP     1              96       GREEN Account  Unclassified
```

Comment: added columns of dataframe to original post. 

The "0,1,...13" are the index of the dictionaries in the list. Those are not the dataframe.

Comment: @snek Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) of input dataframe and what criteria do you need/output dataframe?

Comment: @andrej_Kesely  edited the question with sample data and desired output.

Comment: @snek See my edit.

Comment: This is super helpful. It's on the right track. I think it's taking values like ">0" as a string instead of using the > operator. I'll have to look for a workaround for that. I think I need to manipulate the data a little more to get it to work. 

The output is also only 75k rows instead of 84k. Doing a little investigation on what rows are missing

Comment: @andrej_Kesely is there a way to implement wildcards so that when one of the values in the 'rules' dictionary has "*TEST*" it's searching all strings in the data for the word "Test"? Right now it is returning only exact matches and not anything containing 'test'

Comment: @snek I'd recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow. Put sample (small) input/expected output there a code what you tried. I'll try to look at it.